# how to make table row fit to width of screen in android

Tags: android, textview, fill

I am developing android application which generating results dynamically with table layout. Table rows are generating dynamically. Each table row contains two text views. but the results are not filling total screen.
How to fill total width of screen with two text views of table row.
pleas help me.

Comment: Add your code here. How did we know what you tried?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

And I think It would be better to use ListView with adapter. 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both your TableLayout and TableRow has

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Else please post both xml layout code